# Select statement REF oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help with creating a select statement that will use a ref.

I managed to insert the values fine but when i try to extract the values with a where statement the output is either that the datatype is wrong or it will output the two tables and the data they both contain.

this is just an example:

```
Create or replace table1_Type as object {
 id integer,
 dateStart date,
 etc varchar2(20));
}
/
```

`create table table1 of table1_type;`

```
Create or replace table2_type as object
 id integer,
 items varchar2(30),
 datePurchased varchar2(20),
 table1_Ref REF table1_type);
/
```

`create table table2 of table2_type;`

so i tried

```
Select * from table2 a, table1 b where table1.id = table2.table1_ref
Select * from table2 a, table1 b where table1.id = deref(b.table1_ref)
```

which does not work.

Iam new to this so sorry if i didnt explain properly. What i am trying to do is to select the items for example that were purchased by table1/id  so the output should only display 
the items that were purchased by a certain id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create or replace type table1_Type as object (
 id integer,
 dateStart date,
 etc varchar2(20));
-- TYPE TABLE1_TYPE compiled

create table table1 of table1_type;
-- table TABLE1 created.

Create or replace type table2_type as object(
 id integer,
 items varchar2(30),
 datePurchased varchar2(20),
 table1_Ref REF table1_type);
-- TYPE TABLE2_TYPE compiled

create table table2 of table2_type;
--table TABLE2 created.

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(table1_Type(1, SYSDATE, 'etc1...'));
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(table1_Type(2, SYSDATE, 'etc2...'));

SELECT  REF(t)
FROM    table1 t
WHERE   id = 1;
-- [TST.TABLE1_TYPE]

DECLARE
    l_table_1_id_1  REF table1_Type;
    l_table_1_id_2  REF table1_Type;
BEGIN
    SELECT  REF(t)
    INTO    l_table_1_id_1
    FROM    table1 t
    WHERE   id = 1;

    SELECT  REF(t)
    INTO    l_table_1_id_2
    FROM    table1 t
    WHERE   id = 2;

    INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (21, 'item21', SYSDATE, l_table_1_id_1);
    INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (22, 'item22', SYSDATE, l_table_1_id_2);
END;
-- anonymous block completed

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1;
-- 2
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2;
-- 2

SELECT * FROM table1;
/*
1   2013-06-16 03:51:50 etc1...
2   2013-06-16 03:52:05 etc2...
*/

SELECT * FROM table2;
/*
21  item21  2013-06-16 04:06:26 [TST.TABLE1_TYPE]
22  item22  2013-06-16 04:06:26 [TST.TABLE1_TYPE]
*/

SELECT  *
FROM    table1 t1
JOIN    table2 t2
ON      REF(t1) = t2.table1_Ref;
/*
1   2013-06-16 03:51:50 etc1... 21  item21  2013-06-16 04:06:26 [TST.TABLE1_TYPE]
2   2013-06-16 03:52:05 etc2... 22  item22  2013-06-16 04:06:26 [TST.TABLE1_TYPE]
*/
```

Comment: Ty for your reply, I ran the query but it still shows all of the items in the table. So in this case if someone in Table1 ordered 4 items, the items in table2 would have their own ids but will also contain the table1_ref which will contain the id of the person who ordered the items. What ive been trying to do is to select * from table2 where table1s id = 1. so only items ordered by id 1 are displayed.

Comment: Sry the_silk your answer is perfect.. Ty so much.. all i had to do was add ( And id = 1) and it works..